# Trouble getting Vapor to work with Xcode 8 beta 3

Tags: swift, vapor

I was following the instructions [here](https://vapor.readme.io/docs/install-toolbox), but was not able to get vapor working on my mac. Here're my xcode and swift versions

```
Xcode 8.0
Build version 8S174q

Apple Swift version 3.0-dev (LLVM 8fcf602916, Clang cf0a734990, Swift 000d413a62)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

When I try to install the toolbox using this command

```
curl -sL toolbox.qutheory.io | bash
```

The installation is unsuccessful and yields this message

```
⚠️  It looks like your Command Line Tools version is incorrect.
Make sure Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools is set correctly.
Correct: Xcode 8.0 (8S162m)
Current: Xcode 8.0
Build version 8S174q

⚠️  It looks like your Swift install location has been modified.
Correct: /usr/bin/swift
Current: /Users/<name>/.swiftenv/shims/swift

❌  Incompatible

Reason: Invalid Swift version
Output must contain 'swiftlang-800.0.33.1'

Current 'swift -version' output:
Apple Swift version 3.0-dev (LLVM 8fcf602916, Clang cf0a734990, Swift 000d413a62) Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

  Visit our docs for step-by-step instructions on installing Swift correctly.
http://docs.qutheory.io

  or Join our Slack and we'll help you get setup.
http://slack.qutheory.io
```

From this, I can gather that my swift location is wrong (I don't remember changing it) and that my xcode build number is wrong (because xcode beta 2 is no longer available for download, so I got xcode beta 3.)

Can anybody help me to get this working without changing too much, or is this framework still too finicky to work with a slightly different setup?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's impossible to create packages that work between different Swift 3 development previews because of how much changes in each preview. Things that compiled today might not compile tomorrow and there is no way to selectively target a given preview in code.

Because of this, the Swift version declared in https://github.com/qutheory/vapor#-current-environment for a given Vapor version must be the one used.

Vapor 0.14 relied on the Swift 3.0 preview 2 version that comes with Xcode 8 beta 2. There is currently no way to download Xcode 8 beta 2 now that Apple has stopped hosting it upon the release of Xcode 8 beta 3. That was an oversight.

Vapor 0.15 will not rely on Xcode 8 beta previews and should be released in a few days.

Comment: Vapor 0.15 was released today!

Answer (score 0):

Open Xcode and make sure the correct SDK is selected:
  Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools

Select XCode 8

Then continue with the tutorial you are following.